# Kendo Grid update jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid with dynamic buttons, so after update I need to reload the grid to show/hide buttons, but it's not working :(

Here's my grid:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({        
    dataSource: {

        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/CentroCusto/Lista",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false
            },                
            update: {
                url: "/CentroCusto/Salvar",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                complete: function (data) {

                    if (data.status == 500) {
                        alert('Ocorreu um erro ao salvar o registro.');
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                    }
                }
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {

                if (operation == "update") {

                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options) };
                }

            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                    Id: { type: "number" },
                    Codigo: { type: "string", editable: false },
                    Descricao: { type: "string", editable: false },
                    Empresa: { type: "string", editable: false },
                    AprovadorId: { type: "number", editable: false },
                    NomeAprovador01: { type: "string", editable: true, validation: { required: true } },
                    PercentualLimite: { type: "number", editable: true, validation: { required: true, max: 100 } },
                    Status: { type: "string", editable: false },
                    AprovadorN01: { defaultValue: 1, field: "AprovadorN01" },
                    AprovadorN02: { defaultValue: 1, field: "AprovadorN02" },
                    AprovadorN03: { defaultValue: 1, field: "AprovadorN03" },
                    AprovadorN04: { defaultValue: 1, field: "AprovadorN04" },
                    NomeAprovador02: { type: "string", editable: false },
                    Aprovador03: { type: "number", editable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                    NomeAprovador03: { type: "string", editable: true, validation: { required: true } },
                    Aprovador04: { type: "number", editable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                    NomeAprovador04: { type: "string", editable: true, validation: { required: true } }
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 20,
        serverPaging: false,
        serverFiltering: false,
        serverSorting: false
    },        
    height: 450,
    selectable: true,
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    dataBound: gridDataBound,
    columns: [{ field: "Codigo", title: "Código" },
              { field: "Descricao", title: "Descrição" },
              { field: "Empresa", title: "Empresa" },
              { field: "AprovadorN01", title: "Aprovador N01", editor: aprovadorDropDown, template: "#=AprovadorN01.Nome#" },
              { field: "AprovadorN02", title: "Aprovador N02", editor: aprovador02DropDown, template: "#=AprovadorN02.Nome#" },
              { field: "AprovadorN03", title: "Aprovador N03", editor: aprovador03DropDown, template: "#=AprovadorN03.Nome#" },
              { field: "AprovadorN04", title: "Aprovador N04", editor: aprovador04DropDown, template: "#=AprovadorN04.Nome#" },
              { field: "PercentualLimite", title: "% Limite", width: "10%", format: "{0:n}" },
              { field: "Status", title: "Status", width: "10%" },
              {
                  command: [
                    {
                        name: "edit",
                        text: { edit: "Ativar", update: "Salvar", cancel: "Cancelar" },
                        className: "btn-successo",
                        imageClass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'
                    },

                    {
                        name: "inativar",
                        text: "Inativar",
                        className: "btn-excluir",
                        click: Inativar,
                        imageClass: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'
                    },

                    {
                        name: "edit",
                        text: { edit: "Alterar", update: "Salvar", cancel: "Cancelar" },
                        className: "btn-alterar"
                    }
                  ]
                  , width: "180px"
              }


    ],
        editable: {
            update: true,
            mode: "popup"
        },
        cancel: function (e) {
            $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
        },
        edit: function (e) {
            e.container.kendoWindow("title", "Alterar Centro de Custo");
        }    
    });

    function gridDataBound() {
    $("#grid tbody tr .btn-successo").each(function () {
        var currentDataItem = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));

        //Check in the current dataItem if the row is editable
        if (currentDataItem.Status == "Ativo") {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    })

    $("#grid tbody tr .btn-excluir").each(function () {
        var currentDataItem = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));

        //Check in the current dataItem if the row is editable
        if (currentDataItem.Status == "Inativo") {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    })

    $("#grid tbody tr .btn-alterar").each(function () {
        var currentDataItem = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));

        //Check in the current dataItem if the row is editable
        if (currentDataItem.Status == "Inativo") {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    })

    if ($('#canEdit').val().toUpperCase() == "FALSE") {
        $('#grid').find(".btn-alterar").hide();
        $('#grid').find(".btn-successo").hide();
        $('#grid').find(".btn-excluir").hide();
    }
}
```

What happens is that when I get an error, the error message inside complete on update event is shown, but when the update succeed the instruction `$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read()` is not being called.
I would like to know if there's another way to do that, like save using $.ajax or if there's another event to call after "Update Success".

**-----------------------------------------------------------------**

**UPDATE**

I changed the 'data' to 'e' in the complete method under update and it's working now.

Comment: The `complete` under the `update` action is called but the `read()` isn't, Is that right? Did you debuged inside that callback ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown the read and update are called, only the complete isn't. I debbuged using firebug